# how to convert string to float in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, removing-whitespace

when I try the code:

```
clean_subdata['Tonn'] = clean_subdata['Tonn'].astype(float)
```

the output is :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2\xa0188.5'
```

than I tried :

```
clean_subdata['Tonn'] = clean_subdata['Tonn'].replace(r'\n','', regex=True)
```

But it's doesn't remove the whitespaces. can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove all non digit or dot characters:

```
clean_subdata['Tonn'] = (clean_subdata['Tonn'].str.replace(r'[^\d.]',
                                                           '', regex=True)
                                              .astype(float)
                         )
```